# How to inject configuration properties to a service in Spring testing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

So I have a configuration properties bean

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "amount")
public class AmountProperties {
    private BigInteger minimum;
    private BigInteger maximum;
}
```

This configuration properties bean is used in a service

```
@Slf4j
@Data
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AmountService {
    private final OtherService otherService;

    private final AmountProperties amountProperties;
}
```

Now in testing I have a test class like this

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(value = SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AmountProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:amount-test.properties")
public class CashOutServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private OtherService otherService;

    @Autowired
    private CashOutProperties cashOutProperties;

    @InjectMocks
    private AmountService amountService;

    @Test
    void a() {
        assertNotNull(amountProperties);
        log.debug("{}", amountProperties);
    }

    @Test
    void b() {
        assertNotNull(amountService.getAmountProperties());
        log.debug("{}", amountService.getAmountProperties());
    }
}
```

a test function succeed, but b test function fails. How do I inject amountProperties to amountService?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a real AmountService class because you want to test it but you need to mock other classes used in AmountService class. Also, you can find mockito [documentation](https://site.mockito.org/) says that doesn't mock everything.

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(value = SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AmountProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:amount-test.properties")
public class CashOutServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private OtherService otherService;

    @Autowired
    private AmountProperties amountProperties;

    private AmountService amountService;

    @BeforeEach // If you using junit 4 use @Before annotation
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        amountService = new AmountService(otherService, amountProperties);
    }

    @Test
    void a() {
        assertNotNull(amountProperties);
        log.debug("{}", amountProperties);
    }

    @Test
    void b() {
        assertNotNull(amountService.getAmountProperties());
        log.debug("{}", amountService.getAmountProperties());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix two approaches (`SpringExtension` and `InjectMocks`). If you used `SpringExtension` - that means spring context will be created (use `@MockBean`). If you used `InjectMocks` - that means mocks will be created independently of spring(use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtensions.class)`), in this case `EnableConfigurationProperties` and `TestPropertySource` will not work for your tested service annotated by `@InjectMocks` .
My understanding you want delegate creating of 'AmountProperties' by spring in this case please see my example:

```
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(value = SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AmountProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:amount-test.properties")
@MockBean(OtherService.class)
public class CashOutServiceTest {
        
    @Autowired
    AmountProperties amountProperties;

    @Autowired
    AmountService amountService;

    @Test
    void a() {
        assertNotNull(amountProperties);
        log.debug("{}", amountProperties);
    }

    @Test
    void b() {
        assertNotNull(amountService.getAmountProperties());
        log.debug("{}", amountService.getAmountProperties());
    }
}
```

**PS**. `@MockBean` can also be used at the field level if you want to use in a test.

```
public class CashOutServiceTest {
   @MockBean
   OtherService otherService;
```